# Disable lock screen dimming in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, screen, lock-screen

Apparently, there is no solution to avoid the screen dimming that happens after enabling the lock screen.
I've tried every solution but they seem not to work at all with 16.04.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're talking about the dimming that occurs IMMEDIATELY after a screen lock... just move your mouse/trackpad. If you're talking about dimming that occurs after a preset time, go to system settings/brightness&lock, and change the timeout to never. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema no, I want to *stay* in the touch screen without *ever* touching my PC. For example, to show a slideshow or a photo while my PC is locked. As per my question, I want to *disable* the dimming, not finding a workaround.

Comment: Now, you didn't mention **any** of that in your original question, now did you? I hope you find an answer that works for you. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema I feel my question is self-contained and self-explanatory: I want to avoid the default dimming, *period*. No one had implied any external hack or workaround. Anything I added in the comment was to clarify the issue to *you*, because you were implying a workaround, and it seems to me you are now trying to imply an incomplete question quite incorrectly. Thanks for your time, though.

Comment: Your question **is** incomplete. Your first sentence is your conclusion that there is **no solution**. Your second sentence says you tried **every solution**, but didn't tell us what you **did** try. Remember, **you** came here for a solution. You owe it to the reader to supply as much information as you can. Not wait to get called on it. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema That's because for Ubuntu 16.04 there seems to be buggy behaviour and the feature seems to be impossible to be turned off. I tried *literally* each and every solution found in this site's answers (spent hours looking and trying). Still, even if I am willing to take on the criticism and think about it, suggesting to "move my mouse" seemed to be a bit simplistic. Sorry if I have mistaken any intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04

I have also been trying to figure out how to stop the lock screen from dimming. I can not seem to find anything associated with the screen dimming when going to the lock screen that I can edit/tweak.

I tried all the usual suggestions of

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

but none of them worked.

**** WORKAROUND ****

However invoking an activity once the dimming starts seems to then follow what ever settings you have enabled in the system settings > Brightness & Lock > settings.

The way you can stop it is by locking the screen then typing a few random characters into the password prompt. It will now no longer dim.

It's not a perfect solution by a long shot as the user has to invoke the lock screen manually to get it to work but it may help.