# Disable monitor dimming in lock screen on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lock-screen

After few hours of googling and figuring that the previous answers doesn't seem to for me, I decided to ask you guys how can i prevent screen behind dimmed/sleep, right after entering lock screen mode?

Even after typing my password and then leaving the computer, It's going to sleep after few seconds (about ~twenty).

I tried to apply the answer of this -
[Disable lock screen dimming in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833839/disable-lock-screen-dimming-in-16-04)
but it didn't help my case.

I just want my screen to shine **FOREVER**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that finally worked for me after a LOT of research is

```
xset s off; xset s noblank; xset -dpms
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit here, what do these invocations do and where should they be added to work properly? I presume `s` stands for some screen option?